# how to create json response status in codeigniter

Tags: json, codeigniter, encode

I made json code using json encode, the results are correct, but I want to add a satatus response to the object. How to ?

this my code

```
 public function get(){ 
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $db = $this->M_order->db_order();
        $response =  array();
        $data = array();
            foreach ($db as $key) {
              $data[] = array(
                'id'    => $key->id_user,
                'name'  => $key->name,
                'destination' =>$key->destination
              );
            }
            $response['data'] = $data; 
          echo json_encode($response, TRUE);
    }
```

this result my json

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "amar",
            "destination": "USA"
        }
    ]
}
```

here I want to add a status header in object, like the following ...

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "error": false,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "amar",
      "destination": "USA"
    },
]
}
```

how to create ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question,

```
$response =  array();
$data = array();
foreach ($db as $key) {
     $data[] = array(
                'id'    => $key->id_user,
                'name'  => $key->name,
                'destination' =>$key->destination
     );
}
$response['status'] = 200;
$response['error'] = false;
$response['data'] = $data;
```